# How do I pass a document.querySelector proper as a variable?

Tags: javascript, dom

To apply the DRY principle, I have a lot of document.querySelector in my code and I have created a function as such.

```
const documentQuerySelector = (tag, method, message) => {
  document.querySelector(`.${tag}`)`.${method}`= message;
};
```

Now when I call the function as such:

```
documentQuerySelector('message', '.textContent', '⛔️ No Number!');
```

the text content of the HTML text with class "message" does not get changed to "⛔️ No Number!"

the problem is with the method. When i pass in ".textContent" into the function, and use it in the document query selector as such, document.querySelector(`.${tag}`)`.${method}`= message, it does not recognize the `.${method}`. The reason i know that this is the issue is because when i use the same function and put in ".textContent" instead, it works fine. How do i pass in that property as a variable and how do i use it in the document.querySelector?

Thanks

I tried passing it as a Template Literal and it did not work.

Comment: I think this has multiple issues, the first being that its unclear what you are trying to achieve. You want a <message> tag with the class ".textContent" to contain "⛔️ No Number!"?

Comment: @rx2347 it looks like the function is looking for an element with the class `.message`, as they are appending the class selector `.`  to the `tag`, then they are trying to pass in a method [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) and then finally setting the `textContent` of the `.message` element to the value of the passed `message` argument - part of why it's definitely failing is that `.${method}` would be a string literal (in the example provided) of `..textConent`.

Comment: not sure how that is dryer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want too much DRY here at the expense of flexibility and understandability. Also the function name doesn't infer there's some action on the found element. The action itself is a property setter. What about a method? If you see closer you'll notice you don't save much typing here either. Also other programmers should learn how to handle your function. So my verdict - use `document.querySelector()` as it is, it's much cleaner and imperative.

```
  document.querySelector('.message').textContent = '⛔️ No Number!';
```

If you want to save your typing - use jQuery, I think it's still valid in 2023, and almost everybody will understand your code easily:

```
  $('.message').text('⛔️ No Number!');
```

If you call `querySelector` for the same element several times you can actually do some DRY here and save the element in a variable:

```
  const elMessage = document.querySelector('.message');

  elMessage.textContent = '⛔️ No Number!';
  // some other code
  elMessage.classList.toggle('visible', isMessageVisible);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how it is dryer since you are basically repeating the same thing, just in a different format, but you need to use bracket notation to use a dynamic property. So you code would look something like:

```js
const documentQuerySelector = (selector, property, value) => {
  document.querySelector(selector)[property] = value;
};


documentQuerySelector('.message', 'textContent', '⛔️ No Number!');
```

```html
<div class="message"></div>
```